# Best practice for Agent Queue Users in TFS 2015?

Tags: security, build, tfs-2015

I have installed Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 with update 3 in some sandbox and test environments. In each environment I have to manually add users to the Agent Queue Users group to make it possible for any user to start a build.

Ahmed Al-Asaad has blogged about how to do just that [here](https://lajak.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/fix-tfs-2015-builds-queue-is-empty/).

I have failed to find any Microsoft documentation that describes who should be members of the Agent Queue Users group and it baffles me why the group is empty. The closest documentation I've found is [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/2015) but it just states that I can add users to the group.

It seems counterintuitive that no user per default is allowed to queue a build. That is one of the main reasons for installing TFS in the first place. I want my users to check-in and build all the time.

It also confuses me that I have to add users to the group completely separated from the security administration of the Team Project(s) the user is a member of.

Can anybody point me to some description of best practice on this topic?

Cheers Michael

Answer (score 2):

By default your Build Administrators are given the Administrator role in your agent queues. If you want other people to also be permitted to use the queue, you'll need to add them.

The best practice is to add a group (for example, *{your-project}\Contributors*) to Agent Queue Users. If you want your users can access all agent queues, you can select **All Queues** and then add the group *{your-project}\Contributors* to Agent Queue Users group. If you only want these users to access a particular agent queue, then add the group *{your-project}\Contributors* to the Agent Queue Users group of the particular agent queue.

Comment: Well... the Agent Queues in TFS 2015 are defined on the Collection level so I would have to add every Team Project's Contributers group to the Agent Queue Users group for the Default Queue to make it work?

Comment: I added a group to Agent Queue Users and later I upgraded to TFS 2017 where Agent Queue security is defined on the Team Project level. 

The upgrade process carried over the group I added to the Agent Queue Users group in TFS 2015 but this group no longer exists in TFS 2017. Instead the group I added is now displayed directly in the "Roles for queue" list and I can't remove it. It just changed from Assigned to Inherited even on the All Queues list. 

Inherited from what? What am I missing?

Comment: In TFS 2017, to delete a group or user, hover over it and you'll see there is a red X in the end of the user/group, then you can delete it.

Comment: That was what I expected when I did just that. Instead the Access field for the group changed from Assigned to Inherited. I had no idea where it was inherited from until just now. The group was a member of the group "Agent Queue Users" found under "Security Service Group" in Security for the Collection. I'm guessing it was there because I upgraded from TFS 2015 where Agent Queue security was defined on the Collection and not Team Project level.

Comment: I agree with you.