# Where do you configure permissions for TFS 2015 update 4 Agent pools?

Tags: tfs-2015

I have created several Agent Pools in TFS 2015 update 4 and I see them just fine. I can't fine a document that show where you define access right to the Agent pools. I'm assuming you can assign specific pools to specific team projects?  But I am having a hard time figuring out where you set that up.  I found an article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038798/best-practice-for-agent-queue-users-in-tfs-2015). But its still not clear to me how and where to see permissions for being able to choose an agent pool when you create the build definition.

Answer (score 0):

You don't choose agent pools when you create builds. You choose agent **queues**.

Agent pools are server-level entities.

Agent queues are team project-level entities. An agent queue points to one and exactly one agent pool.

If you don't want a team project to have access to a particular agent pool, don't create a queue that maps to that pool in that team project.